# What jurisdiction applies to invasions of privacy on social media?

Tags: united-states, privacy, jurisdiction, social-media

Suppose user "M", a resident of Maine, posts on Facebook photos or other material that constitute invasion of privacy for user "W", a resident of Washington.

Suppose also that the assertion of invasion of privacy is reasonable enough that any applicable court will take it seriously.

If "W" decides to send "M" a cease and desist order – and possibly to follow up with stronger legal action if "M" ignores the cease and desist order, which jurisdiction applies?

- Washington, because the person who asserts invasion of privacy, "W", is a resident of Washington?
- Maine, because the alleged offender, "M", is a resident of Maine, and the alleged invasion of privacy was posted from Maine?
- California, because the medium of the alleged offense, Facebook, is based in California?
- Federal, because the case crosses state borders and no single state jurisdiction clearly applies?

Although it is not a consideration in the case I'm curious about, a possible further complication would be if "M" had posted the offending materials from yet another jurisdiction, taken photographs somewhere else, etc. I don't need to know this, but it may be useful for others with similar issues.

I would assume that the specific states of residence for "M", "W", and the company could be changed, and the answer would remain the same in terms of whether the jurisdiction is that of the offended person, the offender, and the company – at least for cases within the US. But I think expanding the question beyond US borders is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: The "What jurisdictions" question is partially applicable, but it mainly asks about international jurisdictional issues. I'm asking specifically within the US. I know that there are sometimes jurisdictional conflicts between US states (and appeals court districts), but the rules are, in general, somewhat better defined than in international questions.

Comment: I'll edit the title to clarify that I'm asking specifically about the US.

Comment: ?? There is a tag exactly for this, not in titles.